# How can I directly put a model data into another form's input in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I made a register page and a checkout page (named thankyou in my code) and then i integrated a payment gateway API with my checkout page's form.
The problem I'm getting is, I want to choose the amount of payment from another model's attribute, which I created for the registration page.

To be clear, I want to use `Membership` model's data which the user just entered in Registration page (forms.html) and put it in the `amount` variable of `Thankyou` function.

Here's the model.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here

class MyUser(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',blank=True)
    Full_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    GENDER = (('M','Male'),('F','Female'),('O','Other'))
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER, null=True)
    Phone_Number = models.CharField(max_length=12,unique=True)
    Email = models.EmailField(max_length=264,unique=True)
    Country = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    State = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    City = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=2048)
    MEMBERS = [
    ('2100','2100 Rs Lifetime Membership'),
    ('21000','21000 Rs Lifetime Patron Membership'),
    ('100000','1Lakh Rs S.A.F Trustee'),
    ('1100000','11Lakh Rs S.A.F Patron Trustee'),
    ('5100000','51Lakh Rs S.A.F Board of Trustee'),
    ]
    Membership = models.CharField(max_length=6,choices=MEMBERS, null=True)
    CAREERS = [
    ('BI','Business & Industry'),
    ('JL','Judicial & Legal Services'),
    ('BP','Bureaucrats & Public Servant'),
    ('DP','Defence, Police & Paramilitary Forces'),
    ('NC','NCC Cadets'),
    ('VJ','VIPR Jan(Pujari/Brahmins)'),
    ('PR','Public Representatives'),
    ('NF','Nandanaar Families'),
    ('SO','Social Organisations'),
    ('DO','Doctors'),
    ('YO','Youths'),
    ('OT','Others'),
    ]
    Career = models.CharField(max_length=264,choices=CAREERS,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Full_name)
```

Here's the views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,reverse
from form.models import MyUser
from form.forms import NewUserForm, PaymentForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from instamojo_wrapper import Instamojo




# Create your views here.
def thankyou(request):
    form = PaymentForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("\n\n"+str(request.POST))
        form = PaymentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            response = api.payment_request_create(
            amount = str(data['amount']),
            purpose = data['purpose'],
            send_email = False,
            send_sms = False,
            email = data['email'],
            buyer_name = data['name'],
            phone = data['contact_no'],
            redirect_url = "http://www.example.com/handle_redirect.py"
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect(response['payment_request']['longurl'])
        else:
            form = PaymentForm()

    return render(request, 'thankyou.html', {'form' :form})

def users(request):
    form = NewUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewUserForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('thankyou'))
        else:
            print("FORM INVALID!")

    return render(request,'forms.html', {'form':form})
```

Here's the forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import MyUser


class NewUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Career = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select,choices=MyUser.CAREERS,label='What Best Describes 
You?')
    class Meta():
        model = MyUser
        fields = '__all__'

class PaymentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label = "Name", max_length = 30)
    email = forms.EmailField(label = "Email")
    contact_no = forms.IntegerField(label = "Your contact no" , )
    amount = forms.IntegerField(label = "Amount")
    purpose = forms.CharField(label = "Purpose" , max_length = 200)
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are using a custom user model, if you have done that correctly(it doesn't seems so, your `MyUser` does not extends Django's user model) then you have a `user` instance associated with your request. Use that to query the required field form `MyUser`

As I am not seeing any link between MyUser and authenticated user, I am assuming at least both of them has same email.

```
def thankyou(request):
    user = request.user
    my_user = MyUser.objects.filter(email=user.email)
    membership = my_user.Membership
    # rest of the code
```

Comment: okay how can I extend Django's user model in MyUser exactly? OnetoOne or Foreignkey?

Comment: follow this https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html . It has detailed description.

Comment: Thankyou for your help. This blog will be very useful. I'll create one app from the starting, extending the Django's user model.

Comment: @mantavya.x please consider accepting/upvoting the answer if you think it was correct/helpful.

Comment: for sure, that was a great help.